# PHPMailer default SMTP settings

Tags: phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer.

I have the below given in the code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = 'from@email.com';
$mail->FromName = 'From Name';
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->Body = 'Body';
```

I am not using the below

```
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com";
$mail->Port       = 25;                    
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain";
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";
```

If I am not using the above (host, port, username, pwd, etc...), what will be my default smtp settings information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default PHPMailer uses the `mail()` function, which does not need any SMTP-related settings, so none of those will be used.